# Very basic anonymous function failure in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, anonymous-function

The code is:

```
$function readyFin(jQuery() {
  console.log('ready!');
}

$(document).ready(readyFin);
```

If you can think of a better title for this question, please advise.

I am expecting to see 'ready!' in the javascript console in Chrome, but I do not.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function readyFin() {
      console.log('ready!');
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
       readyFin();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

please see [http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

can you see where the issue is?

Comment: in "$(document).ready" we pass a function "function() { readyFin(); }" in this case, yes it is anonymous, and after "readyFin();" you can add calls to other methods OR do some javascript magic.

Comment: no problem, have fun, and don't forget to read the API for jQuery, it's fun, in two weeks you will master this! (:

Comment: Dorin, Cool name.  Doubtful that I will adapt so quickly.  My general knowledge of programming is not very developed, and I'm also only a novice in Javascript.  I appreciate your bid of confidence, though. :)

Comment: once you get to understand the basics of how you define functions, variables, callbacks, etc.(usually within 1 week, you should get that) then you move to a higher level, now you're in business, you want to learn more and more, it's a never ending race, and you'll enjoy it!

Answer (score 3):

Use `function` instead of `$function`:

```
function readyFin() {
  console.log('ready!');
}
```

Example with anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('ready!');
});
```

Comment: Check second example if you need anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

The corrected example

```
function readyFin(){
  console.log('ready!');
};

$(document).ready(readyFin);
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gagan/Y5AZy/)

Comment: This does not work.  The javascript console does not show "ready!"

Comment: I checked in chrome. It is showing 'ready!' in javascript console. see jsfiddle.

Comment: So it is.  My mistake.  Thank you.